# How to build a console app to multiple servers at once

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, build, console, project

I have a Job Launching system on a server.  It polls our database for any pending jobs then launches the appropriate console app when a job is available.  The Job data is centrally managed in the database and is growing apace so now we have a second server to add to our job processing capacity.

This means the Job Launcher and each console app needs to be released onto the new server.  Every time I have to make updates, a new release must be done for both servers.

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2008 to define a list of build output paths for a release and not just specify one?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a post build event.